# Defining operator() function inside a struct

Tags: c++, boost

While going through one of the tutorials in the Boost library on function wrappers [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html), I came across the following code:

```
  1     boost::function<float (int x, int y)> f;
  2
  3     struct int_div {
  4         float operator() (int x, int y) const { return ((float)x)/y; }
  5     };
  6
  7
  8     int main()
  9     {
 10         f = int_div();
 11         cout << f(5, 3) << endl;
 12         return 0;
 13     }
```

I am trying to wrap my head around about defining a function (`operator()`) inside a struct, and then assigning the struct (using `()` ) to the function wrapper `f`.  Can someone please help me understand what is happening, as far as concepts, in lines 3-5 and 10.

Comment: It's a functor. A `boost::function` holds a callable object and you give it an instance of a class, which you can "call".

Comment: First thing to realize is that in C++, the only difference between a struct and a class is the default visibility of members: for structs it's public, for classes it's private. So really you're defining a very public class here.

Answer (score 10):

In C++, you can provide operators for your types. As function call (`()`) is just another operator in the language, it's possible to define it for your types. So the definition inside `int_div` says "objects of type `int_div` can have the function call operator applied to them (with operands `int` and `int`); such a call will return a `float`."

`boost::function` is a wrapper around anything callable. Since an object of type `int_div` can be used with the function call operator, it's callable and can thus be stored in a `boost::function`. The types match as well - the operator in `int_div` is indeed of type `float(int, int)`.

The parentheses on line 10 are not a call of this operator, however; they are a constructor call. So the line says "create an object of type `int_div` using the default constructor of that type, and assign that object into `f`."

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. But why use the `boost::function`? I think just `int_div f;` instead of `f = int_div();` will work well. Why `f = int_div();`, does it have any advantage? Also, how can `f = int_div();` work? Does the `boost::function` overload assignment (`=`) operator? Oops too many questions :)

Answer (score 6):

If you were using C++11, you could write line #10 as:

```
f = int_div{};
```

which probably help with your confusion.
This line creates a temporary object of type `int_div`, and then assigns it to `f`.

It's not a function call, even though it looks like one.